# What is the difference between a resume and a CV

Tags: resume

I've heard both the term resume and CV used, but they seem to refer to different things. What exactly are the differences, and which should one be using in modern business?

Comment: @Dukeling The top answer on that question answers this but the linked question isn't that well worded, is asking more than just that and is itself closed as a duplicate. I think it makes sense to have the basic question of "resume versus CV" as a separate question since it's such a common question.

Comment: @Lilienthal The title could be improved, but it seems to basically just be asking about the difference between a resume and CV. That duplicate closure is weird, especially considering the vote differences - I was considering flagging it or asking on Meta.

Comment: @Dukeling Good point and good edit. I've closed this as a dupe, merged it and reopened the linked question. That duplicate made zero sense to me.